# .ajax reports success but database insert fails

Tags: jquery

I am very new to jquery/ajax and after searching for two days I'm finally asking for help. There's obviously something basic I'm not understanding.

Here is the .ajax code:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "../ajax/create_employee.php",
    type: 'json',
async: false,
    data: $serialFormData,
    // callback handler that will be called on success
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
```

Here is the php file (create_employee.php) is calls:

```
    <?php
    require ("../models/m_employee.php");
    $myemployee = new m_employee();
    $response = $myemployee->create_new_employee($_POST);
    //echo " php file response = " . $response;
    return $response;
    ?>
```

Here is the object code:

```
        }
$q  = "insert into employee(employee_num,employee_fname,employee_lname,employee_position,employee_start_time,employee_stop_time)";
$q .= "values ('$num','$fname','$lname','$position','$start_time','$stop_time')";

if(!$r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q) ) {
   $data['error'] = "true";
   $data['message'] = "insert failed";      
   $data['success'] = "false";
   return json_encode($data);
}
```

The data returned to the calling file is correct but it doesn't seem to be getting into the 'success' function.  Is the the data returned to the .ajax call supposed to come from my create_employee.php file or is it just the server reporting that the file executed?

Comment: use `echo` instead of return to get the data back to your ajax success function

Answer (score 0):

Try using `echo` instead:

```
<?php
require ("../models/m_employee.php");
$myemployee = new m_employee();
$response = $myemployee->create_new_employee($_POST);
//echo " php file response = " . $response;
echo $response;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not ajax related, but a mysql issue. I would suggest running the php on its own with test data. You may need to re-factor the $_POST variable.

Follow Peacekeepers advice about using an echo instead of a return.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did change it to echo but then also found a problem in the way I was parsing the response. Again. thanks. I'll remember to use echo in the future.